# orthographic scaling opengl viewport

Tags: c, opengl, orthographic

I found [this code sample](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_Introduction.html) that does what I would like to do with modern opengl.

I am trying to figure out how to do this with my code but I am having a really difficult time.

```
/*
 * GL03Viewport.cpp: Clipping-area and Viewport
 * Implementing reshape to ensure same aspect ratio between the
 * clipping-area and the viewport.
 */
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, include glu.h and gl.h

/* Initialize OpenGL Graphics */
void initGL() {
   // Set "clearing" or background color
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Black and opaque
}

void display() {
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear the color buffer with current clearing color

   // Define shapes enclosed within a pair of glBegin and glEnd
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.8f, 0.1f);     // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order
      glVertex2f(-0.2f, 0.1f);     //  so that the normal (front-face) is facing you
      glVertex2f(-0.2f, 0.7f);
      glVertex2f(-0.8f, 0.7f);

      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
      glVertex2f(-0.7f, -0.6f);
      glVertex2f(-0.1f, -0.6f);
      glVertex2f(-0.1f,  0.0f);
      glVertex2f(-0.7f,  0.0f);

      glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); // Dark Gray
      glVertex2f(-0.9f, -0.7f);
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.7f);
      glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); // Dark Gray
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.3f);
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White
      glVertex2f(-0.9f, -0.3f);
   glEnd();

   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);          // Each set of 3 vertices form a triangle
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
      glVertex2f(0.1f, -0.6f);
      glVertex2f(0.7f, -0.6f);
      glVertex2f(0.4f, -0.1f);

      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      glVertex2f(0.3f, -0.4f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
      glVertex2f(0.9f, -0.4f);
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
      glVertex2f(0.6f, -0.9f);
   glEnd();

   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);            // These vertices form a closed polygon
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Yellow
      glVertex2f(0.4f, 0.2f);
      glVertex2f(0.6f, 0.2f);
      glVertex2f(0.7f, 0.4f);
      glVertex2f(0.6f, 0.6f);
      glVertex2f(0.4f, 0.6f);
      glVertex2f(0.3f, 0.4f);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();  // Render now
}

/* Handler for window re-size event. Called back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window is re-sized with its new width and height */
void reshape(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) {  // GLsizei for non-negative integer
   // Compute aspect ratio of the new window
   if (height == 0) height = 1;                // To prevent divide by 0
   GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

   // Set the viewport to cover the new window
   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

   // Set the aspect ratio of the clipping area to match the viewport
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);  // To operate on the Projection matrix
   glLoadIdentity();             // Reset the projection matrix
   if (width >= height) {
     // aspect >= 1, set the height from -1 to 1, with larger width
      gluOrtho2D(-1.0 * aspect, 1.0 * aspect, -1.0, 1.0);
   } else {
      // aspect < 1, set the width to -1 to 1, with larger height
     gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0 / aspect, 1.0 / aspect);
   }
}

/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main() */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);          // Initialize GLUT
   //glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);   // Set the window's initial width & height - non-square
   glutInitWindowSize(1024, 720);   // Set the window's initial width & height - non-square
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutCreateWindow("Viewport Transform");  // Create window with the given title
   glutDisplayFunc(display);       // Register callback handler for window re-paint event
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);       // Register callback handler for window re-size event
   initGL();                       // Our own OpenGL initialization
   glutMainLoop();                 // Enter the infinite event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

There are a few chances that I made to my code for two reasons.
1) I'd like to have 0,0 be the lower left corner and width, height be the upper right hand corner.

2) The second and more confusing part is how do I maintain my pixel coordinates. The example code uses points in the range of -1.0 to 1.0 but I would like to be able to say my quad is 50px by 50px.

currently I create my viewport and projections like this.

```
    point3 eye, center;
    vec3 up;
    vmathP3MakeFromElems(&eye, 0, 0, 0);
    vmathP3MakeFromElems(&center, 0, 0, -1);
    vmathV3MakeFromElems(&up, 0, 1, 0);
    vmathM4MakeLookAt(&v_mat, &eye, &center, &up);

    vec3 trans;
    vmathV3MakeFromElems(&trans, 0, 0, -20);
    vmathM4MakeTranslation(&v_mat, &trans);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    vmathM4MakeOrthographic(&p_mat, 0, width, 0, height, 1, 100);
```

I am currently drawing 1 quad that's defined like this:

```
//3 position, 4 color, 2 texture coordinates
float v_data[] = {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
          -1.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
          1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
          1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

short i_data[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
```

and I setup it's model matrix like this:

```
vmathV3MakeFromElems(&out->scale, texture->width * 0.5f, texture->height * 0.5f, 1);
vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 0, 0, out->scale.x);
vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 1, 1, out->scale.y);
vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 2, 2, 1);
vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 3, 3, 1);

vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 3, 0, (out->scale.x) - (x));
vmathM4SetElem(&out->model_mat, 3, 1, (out->scale.y) + (y));
```

so how can I achieve viewport scaling like in the sample code but being able to use pixels [this might be the wrong approach, i am unsure].

this sample code at the top can be copy pasted and built with this command.

```
gcc -lglut -lGLU -lGL -o glsample glsample.c && ./glsample
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vmathM4MakeOrthographic(&p_mat, 0, width, 0, height, 1, 100);
```

Let's say, that after this line `p_mat` will hold a matrix like this:

```
|1/width                 | -> p_mat[0][0]
|         1/height       | -> p_mat[1][1]
|                   .... |
|                        |
```

This should ensure, that if width and height are in pixels, you'll keep your pixel-perfect scale.
The first sample you provided, however, uses

```
gluOrtho2D(-1.0 * aspect, 1.0 * aspect, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Which doesn't consider screen width and height (only the aspect ratio between them), and you will have a uniform unit scale.

Basically, by dividing or multiplying those two components (by the same number to keep aspect) in the projection matrix (`p_mat[0][0] & p_mat[1][1]`) you can scale your viewport. To achieve pixel-perfect scale, simply set them to 1/width and 1/height.